# How to save specific parts of video into separate videos using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, video-editing

I have a video and I want to obtain specific parts of that video using frame numbers and save them.

For example, if there is a video and it has total 200 frames and I want to extract some specific parts of video say from frame 15 to 30, 50 to 79, etc. and I want to save each of these parts separately.

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('Trademill.mp4')
video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) 
print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)

success,image = cap.read()
count = 0
while success:
cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)          
success,image = cap.read()
count += 1
```

How can I do this using python and OpenCV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import cv2

file = "video.avi"
parts = [(15, 30), (50, 79)]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
ret, frame = cap.read()
h, w, _ = frame.shape

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
writers = [cv2.VideoWriter(f"part{start}-{end}.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (w, h)) for start, end in parts]

f = 0
while ret:
    f += 1
    for i, part in enumerate(parts):
        start, end = part
        if start <= f <= end:
            writers[i].write(frame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

for writer in writers:
    writer.release()

cap.release()
```

Explanation:

1. Import the `cv2` module, define the name of the video file and the parts of the file you want to save into different video files:

```
import cv2

file = "video.avi"
parts = [(15, 30), (50, 79)]
```

2. Define a video capture device to read frames from the video file and read from it once to get the shape of the frames of the video:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
ret, frame = cap.read()
h, w, _ = frame.shape
```

3. Define a fourcc *(four-character code)*, and define a list of video writers; one for every video you want to generate:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
writers = [cv2.VideoWriter(f"part{start}-{end}.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (w, h)) for start, end in parts]
```

4. Define a `while` loop, but before that, define a variable to keep track of which frame the while loop is at in the capture device:

```
f = 0
while ret:
    f += 1
```

5. Using a `for` loop inside the `while` loop, loop through the start and end frames of the parts, using the `enumerate` method to allow the program to access the index of the parts each iteration is at when needed. If the variable defined before the `while` loop is between *(inclusive)* the start and end of the part, write that frame to the corresponding video writer *(using the index provided by the `enumerate` method)*:

```
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(parts):
        if start <= f <= end:
            writers[i].write(frame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

6. Finally, release all the video writers and the capture device:

```
for writer in writers:
    writer.release()

cap.release()
```

Comment: I am getting an error in h, w, _ = frame.shape. When I printed the image it is giving none. Even when I am printing the width and height and of the frames I am getting 0. I have checked the path too it is correct. And the parts of the video I saved aren't playing. Please tell me how should I solve this

Comment: @codexx How did you input your path? Is it the full path to the video?

Comment: I tried to input the whole path and just the name too both are not working

Comment: It is windows. When I print a specific frame, the frame is not displayed and it shows not responding.

Comment: When I replace the line `writers[i].write(frame)` with `cv2.imwrite('new_frame_'+str(frame)+'.jpg',frame)`, it does not write anything. Can you please tell me where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @user42 The thing that went wrong is that you are using the `numpy` array `frame` to be the filename of your images at `str(frame)`. Due to the length of the string, `cv2.imwrite()` failed to write the images. You can reproduce the problem like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoz7C.png Notice how the function returned `False` when the filename is too long.